# Lucas-Kanade algorithm with RANSAC

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, opticalflow, ransac

I want to apply Lucas Kanade algorithm and then use its results for applying RANSAC algorithm. Is it possible to apply both together? I am coding in MATLAB.

Comment: Yes it's possible and no, we aren't going to code it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do? What is your goal here? RANSAC is a robust estimation algorithm, which can be used in many different contexts.

The KLT (Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi, aka Lucas-Kanade) algorithm for tracking points from one image to another is implemented as the `vision.PointTracker` object in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. There is also the `estimateGeometricTransform` function, which uses RANSAC to estimate the geometric transformation between two sets of matched points.  See [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html) to learn how you can use `vision.PointTracker` and `estimateGeometricTransform` to track a face in video.